# Auth::routes(['register' => false]); not working in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Recently I install laravel 8. I am trying to disable registration.
In laravel 7 "Auth::routes(['register' => false]);" it's work.
But laravel 8 it's not working.

Comment: That stuff doesn't come with Laravel by default it is a separate package, which was `laravel/ui` ... so it won't be there in a default install, and in 7 you also had to install that package ... in laravel 8 they want you to use jetstream but it is nothing like `laravel/ui` in any way

Answer (score 2):

You could try this it's work for me.
Add these routes just below the `Auth::routes()` to override the default registration routes. Any request to the `/register` route will redirect to the baseUrl.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'register', function(){
return redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable registration in Laravel 8, remove the line `Features::registration()` or comment out the `Feature` in the `app/config/fortify.php` file

```
'features' => [
    // Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
     Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
         'confirmPassword' => true,
     ]),
],
```

Comment: this file is not exists in config folder, i have laravel 8.x installed

Comment: I think we need to install this one for this answer to work: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel Breeze.
Just remove or comment this lines in routes/auth.php

```
Route::get('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
            ->middleware('guest')
            ->name('register');

Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your route

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'register', function () {
    abort(404);
});
```